# What is straight link to any page of search results in Yahoo?

Tags: search, hyperlink, yahoo

Essential is that my app parses the results of search from Yahoo!. There was easy to define that to get first page I need to from the next URL

```
http://search.yahoo.com/search;_ylt=A0oG7l7PeB5P3G0AKASl87UF?p=<My_Keyword>
```

but what's straight link to any other page from yahoo! search page ? If to see on link there is

```
a href="/search;_ylt=A0oG7mulOyVP3FMAnPlXNyoA?p=java&amp;fr=404_web&amp;fr2=sb-bot&amp;xargs=0&amp;pstart=1&amp;b=11&amp;xa=U7cN_L3AOtj18W09Ud7SkA--,1327926565" title="Results 11 - 20" id="yui_3_3_0_1_1327840165621204"
```

but where is this some param, changing that I can to go to the next page or just to 10 page, for example? Does somebody know about this feature of yahoo? 
By the way, YouTube hasn't such problem, his links are very simple, but Yahoo...

**UPD** Seems to be I defined this params - this is "b=11". Second page has "b=21", the third - "b=31" and so on

Comment: Are you sure that Yahoo allows this? Have you checked their terms of service?

Comment: If Google allows this, why Yahoo doesn't ? I'm not sured that is question of terms of service, sooner this is question of technical standard...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Link directly to specific pages by setting the offset (`b`) correctly.
Yahoo currently shows 10 results on each page, therefore use the following offset:

```
offset = 10 x pagenumber - 9
```

Quick example based on the URL you provided:

```
http://search.yahoo.com/search;_ylt=A0oG7l7PeB5P3G0AKASl87UF?p=<My_Keyword>
```

Page 1 *(offset = 10 x 1 - 9 = 1)*

```
http://search.yahoo.com/search;_ylt=A0oG7l7PeB5P3G0AKASl87UF?p=<My_Keyword>&b=1
```

Page 2 *(offset = 10 x 2 - 9 = 11)*

```
http://search.yahoo.com/search;_ylt=A0oG7l7PeB5P3G0AKASl87UF?p=<My_Keyword>&b=11
```

Page 3 *(offset = 10 x 3 - 9 = 21)*

```
http://search.yahoo.com/search;_ylt=A0oG7l7PeB5P3G0AKASl87UF?p=<My_Keyword>&b=21
```

Note:
I don't know the future, but currently the links above work fine.
Yahoo might change the URL structure any time.

Comment: Thank you very much for such complete response!

Answer (score 0):

What is the role of this parameter "_ylt" ?
I think there is no problem to ignore it.
Yahoo in different country have different content of "_ylt".
And the HTTP has been changed to https://, not http:// .

```
    Taiwan:
https://tw.search.yahoo.com/search?p=soqi+bed&fr=yfp&ei=utf-8&v=0
https://tw.search.yahoo.com/search;_ylt=A8tUwZBhGxlU93YAZHJr1gt.?p=soqi+bed&ei=utf-8&fr=yfp&b=11&pstart=2


    US(eng):
https://search.yahoo.com/search;_ylt=AiVNJTPKVpm9Jag8U.STVL6bvZx4?p=soqi+bed&toggle=1&cop=mss&ei=UTF-8&fr=yfp-t-329&fp=1
https://search.yahoo.com/search;_ylt=AwrSbDzyGRlUoG0AUn1XNyoA?p=soqi+bed&ei=UTF-8&fr=yfp-t-329&fp=1&b=11&pstart=7


    Japan:
http://search.yahoo.co.jp/search;_ylt=A7dPKW9aHBlUDm4A5b2JBtF7?p=soqi+bed&search.x=1&fr=top_ga1_sa&tid=top_ga1_sa&ei=UTF-8&aq=&oq=&afs=
http://search.yahoo.co.jp/search?p=soqi+bed&tid=top_ga1_sa&ei=UTF-8&pstart=1&fr=top_ga1_sa&b=11
```